# Planar graph, Minimum degree of a vertex at least 3 and Number of faces of a graph

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

**Lemma:** Suppose that a plane simple graph on $n ≥ 4$ vertices with the minimal degree of
a vertex at least $3$ does not have faces of degree $4$ or $5$. Prove that there are at least $4$ faces of
degree $3$ (triangles) in this graph.

I saw that a similar question was asked by  **Dolva** [Planar graph, number of faces, minimum vertex degree 3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3511152/planar-graph-number-of-faces-minimum-vertex-degree-3). Where the Handshaking lemma and  Euler's formula $v-e+f=2$ were suggested. But I am still stuck.

Any advice or help is welcome. **Thanks in Advance!**

Comment: @kabenyuk I actually drew a graph using n=4 satisfying the given condition but it is not containing 4 faces of degree 3.

Comment: @Kabenyuk could please explain in details how you got proved it

Comment: @Violet It would be interesting to look at your drawing.
Note that this is not a proof, just hints.

Comment: @kabenyuk yeah I understood what I did wrong....I forgot to consider the outer region face and how to calculate it's degree....

Comment: That's what I thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

1. $v\leq2e/3$;
2. $3k+6(f-k)\leq2e$, $k\leq3$, then $f\leq e/3+k/2$;
3. $2=v-e+f\leq 2e/3-e+e/3+k/2=k/2\leq3/2$.

Comment: I did not understand how did you get the second one

Comment: Hello @kabenyuk please  could you still  explain the propositions (1) and (2). And what step do I need to take further. I have been trying to solve it but still stuck.  thanks

Comment: Let $V$ be the vertex set of our graph.

Since $\sum_{u\in V}{\rm deg}(u)=2e$ and $
{\rm deg}(u)\geq3$ for each vertex $u$ of $V$, it follows that $v\leq2e/3$.

Let $\cal F$ denote the set of all faces
and $k$ denotes the number of faces of degree 3.

Since $\sum_{F\in\cal F}d(F)=2e$ and $d(F)\geq6$ or $d(F)=3$,
it follows that $f\leq e/3+k/2$.

Comment: Thanks  @kabenyuk it was helpful